# actionscript 3 , calling data from website

Tags: flash, actionscript

hello i was wondering if i can call data from a website in action script/flash e.g a RSS feed or a news piece , mainly to put on a mobile device. i ran it on my desktop and it asks for permission then nothing happened? any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can easily do that.

Now, in your case the flash player security model probably prevented you from communicating with the internet if you opened that file from your hard drive. A popup should have appeared that had an OK button and Setting button if you opened it in the flash player... for the IDE it should have just failed but outputted an error to the output screen.

I'm having a hard time finding the exact thing on google, but basicaly, among many other things, the .swf is sandboxed and can only comunicate with it's local sandbox, specifficaly, if you open it via internet, then no hard drive acess (local files) and if you open it from your harddrive, no internet access (except if you set as trusted after you click on "settings" button on that popup). Similar prohibitions exist for crossdomain scripting on the net but can be relaxed...

If you are looking or a huge read, try this, some things are relevant. I can't find a smaller tutorial on this :)

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/flash_player10_security_wp.html

Also, try this as well, the text should explain how to set it as trusted if you are not using the Flash IDE to create that .swf.

http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html
(just read the whole text on the webpage until you understand it, if you are having that popup, it's not hard, but needs to be read carefully to be understood)

If you are using the ide, try FILE/Publish settings/Flash tab and then in the lower part of the window tweak Local Playback Security to internet only...

Let me know if you need more clarifications...

Comment: thank you mate il get back to you when ive had a read and an attempt, its for an iphone more than anything would that cause the same issues?

Comment: nah im really stuck i really dont get it , i just want to make a rss reader in flash but it just dont wanna work :(

Comment: a little bit of code would help... I dont' know about iphone though, the cs5 converter for ios could be doing a lot of shanangians... but access to internet resources for iphone applications should be a priority for adobe, so it should not be impossible, unless iphone itself is restricting it somehow